# Android: can't open Uri output stream

Tags: android, uri, outputstream

Hell all,
I'm not able to get an output stream from a uri I've just created.

Manifest:

```
        <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.root.capture.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

file paths:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures/" />
```

Code:

```
 /*Checked directory content: yes, Pictures directory exists*/
    File Ls[]=getFilesDir().listFiles();

    Uri MyUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.root.capture.fileprovider", new File(getFilesDir().toString() + "/Pictures/sorgente.jpg"));

    OutputStream OS;
    try {
        OS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(MyUri);
    } catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        /*Always there*/
        return;
    }
```

I've thought that the problem was the fact that the file did not yet exist, and tried to create it: but the creation failed. So I can't create the file directly, nor use the content provider getOutputStream. How can I write on a file in Pictures?
Thank you

Comment: "So I can't create the file directly" -- why not? You do not need `FileProvider` to work with `getFilesDir()` inside your own app. You need `FileProvider` to allow *other apps* to work with your app's `getFilesDir()`. In this case, does `Pictures/` exist?

Comment: For some reason the creation of a FileOutputStream in the directory Pictures fails. Instead, the exact some code works with another name folder... Pictures1, for example. It seems the the <files-path> declaration made Pictures a somehow special directory, in which the app itself can't write any more.

Comment: Hello, deleting and recreating the Pictures folder solved the problem. I can't explain the reason why. Thank you.